# In Matlab, is there a way to take in a formula as parameter input?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, program-entry-point

This might seem like a strange thing to do, which it probably is. In my main (or how you call it in matlab) I would like to have all the information needed for the program to run. A change of variables or formulas should only happen in my main.

For example I would like to change the number of iterations and the formula of the hypothese in my main and let other function use these, instead of declaring them within the function themselves and having to edit it all over the place. The problem I face is not knowing how to do this properly for hypothese_formula and wonder if there is a better way of doing this?

```
function prog1()
   iterations = 1;
   hypothese_formula = x^2;

   doSomethingWithFormulaAndIterations(hypothese_formula, iterations);
end
```

Practical: I would to do linear regression with a hypothesis of the formula and specific starting values of theta and don't want them to be hidden within a function. I don't know how to declare global formula's.

Comment: I think you want a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

```
function prog1()
   iterations = 1;
   hypothese_formula = @(x) x.^2

   doSomethingWithFormulaAndIterations(hypothese_formula, iterations);
end
```